# Facebook Graph API get First and Last name from PSID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, message, file-get-contents

I have setup a FB Webhook to notify my technicians when a user messages my business page.  The notification works and I get the message and the sender's ID (PSID) but I can't seem to get the sender's first and last name per the documentation found here :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile

- I have been granted Advanced Access with the "Business Asset User Profile Access" as required.
- The App is in Live mode (not development mode)
- Messaging permissions are granted

I need to turn the returned "Sender ID (PSID)" into a First and Last name.  According to the documentation, I need to send a request like this :

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/<PSID>?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

So my code looks like this :

```
function get_basic_info($id, $access) {
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic&access_token='.$access;
    $info = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    return $info;
}
```

I would then call the function using : $fbuser = get_basic_info($sender, $fb_access_token);

This will ALWAYS return **NULL** when messaging my business page from any Facebook account.... except from my personal account which owns the business page.  If I message my business account from my personal account that owns the business, this is what I get back :

```
{"first_name":"Tim","last_name":"My_Last_Name","profile_pic":"Profile_Picture_URL","id":"My_FB_ID"}
```

The access token I am using is generated from the App Dashboard > My_App > Messenger (under Products, left side) > Settings > Access Tokens > Generate Token (Next to the Business Page I own).

What am I doing wrong?  It works when I personally message my own business page, but not when anyone else messages.  Thank you for ANY help!

Answer (score 1):

So to update this with an answer for those who may be looking, here it goes....  Don't use the Sender ID (PSID) as the documentation states, use the Message ID.

```
function get_basic_info($id, $access) {
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'?fields=from&access_token='.$access;
    $info = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    return $info;
}
```

Usage :

```
$fbuser = get_basic_info($message_id, $FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN);
$fb_name = $fbuser['from']['name'];
```

Unfortunately, you cannot get the Profile Picture, but this is as far as I needed to get anyways.

Enjoy!